# Image.FromStream OutOfMemory Exception

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get image from MemoryStream. When in MemoryStream I have a big JPG image (which size increases from 38MB to over 1.3GB after converting to bitmap in step commented as problematic) I get an OutOfMemory exception. With smaller images everything works fine. How to handle such problem? Acceptable solution for me is to resize/rescale image stored in `_imgArray` below 1.3GB. Is it possible to do this before invoking `Image.FromStream` method?

```
public static Image GetImageFromByteArray(byte[] _imgArray)
{
    Image imgFromArray = null;
    MemoryStream stream = null;
    try
    {
        stream = new MemoryStream(_imgArray, 0, _imgArray.Length);
        imgFromArray = Image.FromStream(stream, true);//this line throws an Out of memory exception
    }
    catch(OutOfMemoryException)
    {
        Error.Warning("Das Bild ist zu groß!");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new FacadeException("Fehler beim Laden des Bildes.", ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        if (stream != null)
        {
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
    return imgFromArray;
}
```

Comment: where is the big jpg from?

Comment: JPG file is from file, and is stored in memory in byte array (_imgArray).

Comment: You can never load such an image in a 32-bit process.  Right-click the EXE project > Properties > Build tab > untick "Prefer 32-bit".  You don't prefer it.

Comment: 1.3GB jpg? How big in pixels is that image???

Comment: As I wrote below:"Unfortunately I cant change architecture of this application. I have to find some other workaround to secure application against too big pictures."

Comment: His size is: 21600x21600 (466.56MPixels)

Comment: You will either have to call an external program to convert the file into something that is uncompressed, so that you can use random access to access the individual parts of the image **or** find a class library able to decode a jpg in parts **or** write such a tool yourself.

Comment: A 32-bit program can't handle that image as a single image through the built-in image classes.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason:**

The OutOfMemory expection will be throwed when you create an object that is greater than ~ 1.3GB on an application 32bit(x86).

**Solution:**

Try to change your applicationo to 64bit(x64) as the picture below:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately I cant change architecture of this application. I have to find some other workaround to secure application against too big pictures.

Comment: If memory is limited by architecture and the image is such a big one you should avoid keeping both - the file data and bitmap data - in memory.

Comment: What is your purpose to return a big Image object? To show it on an application or ??

Comment: Yes, I have a form which allowes to show preview of this image and zoom his details.

Comment: So, I think you have to use some tricks:

- Split the large image to many smaller images or just read a part of large image to show on.

- Or you can down the image resolution before you load it to Image object and show on. End-user doesn't really need to see so high resolution image

Comment: You mean down the resolution in some external application? Remember that I can't read this image therefore I can't resize it in a preceeding step.

Comment: Why don't you use another library to reduce the resolution first?